# trim html entities from string variable in nsis

Tags: newline, nsis, trim, linefeed

I am trying to find out the way to get rid of the

> `&#x0D;&#x0A;`

symbols from string.

I have tried Trim and CharStrip functions, but with no success.

Code snipp:

```
  ${CharStrip} "&#x0D;&#x0A;" "$R4" "$R3"
  !insertmacro WriteXMLPathAttr "/configuration/FTGAuth" "value" "$R3"
```

WriteXMLPathAttr macro:

```
  ${xml::RootElement} $R1 $R0
  !ifdef DEBUGMODE_NSISDBG
    nsisdbg::sendtolog /NOUNLOAD " root : $R1"
  !endif  
  ${xml::GotoPath} "${XML_PATH}" $R1
  !ifdef DEBUGMODE_NSISDBG
    nsisdbg::sendtolog /NOUNLOAD "GotoPath ${XML_PATH} result: $R1 "
  !endif
  ${xml::SetAttribute} "${XML_PARAM}" "${XML_VARIABLE}" $R1
  !ifdef DEBUGMODE_NSISDBG
    nsisdbg::sendtolog /NOUNLOAD "SetAttribute result $R1 : ${XML_VARIABLE} "
  !endif
```

Thanks for any help!

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with the [Replace Sub String macro](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Replace_Sub_String_%28macro%29) from the [String functions  section](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Category%3aString_Functions) of the wiki.

There is also [Another string replace](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Another_String_Replace_%28and_Slash/BackSlash_Converter%29) alternative.